# Customer Dashboard New Tab failure

Tags: magento2, php, magento-2.1, customer, sellers-dashboard

I have made new custom tabs for my customer account dashboard. however, when I click the custom navigation link. It cannot find my controller action.
[image]
[image]

### I cannot figure out the mistakes..so I need your help

Folder tree

[image: My module structure]

---

customer_account.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-training-material-link" after="customer-account-navigation-address-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">trainingmaterial/customer/index</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string"> Training Material</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-link" after="customer-account-navigation-training-material-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">trainingmaterial/customer/newsletter</argument>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Newsletter</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>            
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" remove="true"/>                               
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

---

trainingmaterial_customer_index.xml

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Training Material</argument>
            </action>
     </referenceBlock>
     <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="training">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">training</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

---

trainingmaterial_customer_newsletter.xml

```
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="customer_account"/>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Newsletter</argument>
            </action>
     </referenceBlock>
     <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="training">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">training</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

---

Index.php

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

 public function execute() {

    $this->_view->loadLayout();

    $this->_view->renderLayout();
  }

}
```

---

Newsletter.php

```
class Newsletter extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

 public function execute() {

    $this->_view->loadLayout();

    $this->_view->renderLayout();
  }

}
```